# What is the most simple way to make a local notification in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm working on a Xamarin application and I'm very confused about making a local notification because it has a lot of details and channels things and others.
does anyone know how to make a simple notification

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to make it simple you need to know:

1. Android Notification is an element with several parts (title, description, logo...), that can be shown in the blocked screen or notification bar, that play a sound or vibrate, and that brings you to an application or make an action. You can control all of those elements.
2. To let the user the control of what the want to receive or not, devs **must** put their notification in channel, otherwise [they won't work in Android 8.0 (Oreo)](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) or above.

The steps are:

1-Create notification channel at the beggining of your Activity, inside OnCreate()

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        //No need to create notification channel
        return;
    }
var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.Default)
                  {
                      Description = description
                  };

var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

2-Create notification with all of its components

```
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
              .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
              .SetContentIntent(new Intent()) // Just do nothing
              .SetContentTitle("Simple notification") // Set the title
              .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
              .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
              .SetContentText("Description of the notification body"); // the message to display.
```

3-Put your notification in the channel

```
var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
```

The whole example is taken from the [official Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough), I really encourage you to take a few minutes to read [the notifications docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications), where you can learn about them in detail, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but the thing that I keep getting is the red lines keep telling me that a  function doesn't exist in the context menu <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ehXjz4m.png">here's a picture</img>

Comment: Take a look to the official Xamarin docs I put to get through de complete example. The error you're getting is related to the way you have declared the names of your app (like the channel name), and GetString must be called from an Activity

Comment: Nothing works with me

Comment: try the sample on your side:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/localnotifications/